# Publish Video Facebook Using PHP SDK 4.0

Tags: php, facebook, video

I am reading the developers Facebook tutorial, and this is the explanation they give about publishing videos using PHP SDK 4.0:

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{page-id}/videos',
  array (
    'source' => '{video-data}',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

They also explain that "Videos must be encoded as multipart/form-data and published to graph-video.facebook.com instead of the regular Graph API URL."

I have the video in my server (http://www.example.com/videos/video.mp4) or in a folder in my application directory (.../videos/video.mp4), and don't know how to "use" it in this example of the PHP SDK 4.0.

I saw some exemples using a form to post the video, but I want to do it automatically, without the need to choose manually the file to upload.

Anyone know to publish the video that I have in my server, using the PHP SDK? What should I put in the {video-data} in the "source" field?

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem:

```
// Get the GraphUser object for the current user:
try {
  $response = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 
    'POST', 
    '/page_id/videos',
    array (
    'description' => 'test',
    'source' => new CURLFile('path/to/file/video.wmv', 'video/wmv'),
    )
))->execute()->getGraphObject();

   echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Some other error occurred
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `'source' => '@/path/to/file'` as it's a wrapper around cURL.

Note that if this is a large file it might be better to do this as a background process - if the file takes a minute or two to upload from your server the user will be sitting there wondering if something isn't working right.