# Upload Video to Facebook using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to write a PHP script, that uploads a video from the server to the user's Facebook wall.

Here is the script:

```
try{
  $response = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'POST',
    '/me/videos',
    array (
      'source' => "@".realpath('123.mp4')
    )
  ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
} catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But I get an exception:

```
(#353) You must select a video file to upload
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
I'm using PHP 5.4.36-0+deb7u3 on my server.

Comment: Please check this question it may helps you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604151/publish-video-facebook-using-php-sdk-4-0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604151/publish-video-facebook-using-php-sdk-4-0

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I can't use CURLFile, because it was introduced in php 5.5. The second answer in the question you mentioned is exactly what I'm doing, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `realpath` just fills in the full **path** of the video file *on your server*. You need to send the **video data** in the request.

Would it be able to update to 5.5.x? This series was introduced on 2013-07-18, almost two years ago(!). Alternatively, I believe you can plugin curl support to your php configuration.